# getResources as global variable

Tags: java, android, oop

I have simply activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends MainActivity {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        final Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Resources resources = getResources();
                String text = resources.getString(R.string.test);
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        final Button click2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);

        click2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Resources resources = getResources();
                String text = resources.getString(R.string.test2);
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This working good, but I am learning Android and i would like modify this. I would like use getResources as global variable:

```
public class TestActivity extends MainActivity {    

    Resources resources = getResources(); //ADD HERE!

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        final Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //REMOVE!
                String text = resources.getString(R.string.test);
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        final Button click2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);

        click2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //REMOVE!
                String text = resources.getString(R.string.test2);
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but this return MAIN EXCEPTION. Why? How can i make it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to put it as a global instance, it is already bounded to the activity which you can directly get its instance from the activity through calling its name.

**sample:**

```
click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = TestActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.test);
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

No need to assign it to a varialbe that `getResource` will return the same instance of it. So it is unessesary to declare it as a global variable.

The second snippet of code fails because you are directly getting `getResources()` before the activity's `onCreate()` thus catching exception.

Comment: thanks, but if I would like to shorten "TestActivity.this.getResources()" to "res"? how can i make it? :)

Comment: @darlik I would not really recommend for you to use global instance of it. it is really a bad design, but if you really want it then set global instance(`Resources res;`) of it but initialized it in your `onCreate()` -> `res = getResources()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesnt answer the users question.

Comment: @r2DoesInc why so?? I am simply telling him it is a bad practice.

Comment: Whether it is or not, the OP asked how to set it as a global variable, never did he ask if there was a better way to do it, and therefore your answer is offtopic.

Comment: @r2DoesInc it is stackOverflow and what we do is to tell the right way not the other way around

Comment: `getResources()` does NOT have a global scope as it requires a `Context`. Again, this does not answer the OPs question. It is a good solution to his bad code, but it is not a solution at all to his proposed question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `TestActivity.this` instead use `getActivity()` also `getResource().getString()` would replaced with `getString()`

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = getString(R.string.test);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TestActivity extends MainActivity {    

    ***Resources resources;***

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        ***resources = getResources();***

        final Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = resources.getString(R.string.test);
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        final Button click2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);

        click2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = resources.getString(R.string.test2);
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```